# Docker RabbitMQ in detached mode logging

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ in the docker container in detached mode.  I am doing this so I can set some values using rabbitmqctl.

I added tail -f /dev/null so the container doesn't shutdown

However when I do this, I get no logging from the docker container.

How can I run rabbitmq-server -detached AND get logging to the "console"?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker logs -f [container name or container ID]
```

will give you the container log. If rabbitmq logs to an specific file you can then do:

```
docker exec [container name or container ID] tail -f [PATH to the rabbot mb log file]
```

To get the container ID or name in case that you don't know it use:

```
docker ps
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to set `RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE` to a shared volume directory.

In your dockerfile, add:

`ENV RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE="/var/log/foo"`

Then, run the container with:

`docker run -d -v /var/log/bar:/var/log/foo your_image`

Then you can get the data directly in your host in the directory `/var/log/bar`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? `/var/log/bar:/var/log/foo`.